# How to correctly $push an object into MongoDB scheme property, type: array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I have a Ads model schema property of:

```
viewCount: {
    type: []
}
```

And I have an update function where I want to add an object to that array like so:

```
exports.updateAd = function(req, res) {
    var conditions = { _id: req.body._id };
    var update = {};
    if (req.body.viewCount) {
        update.$push = {
            viewCount: {
                'date': Date.now(),
                'user': req.body.user
            }
        }
    }
    Ads.update(conditions, update, {}, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.jsonp({
            'result': result
        });
    });
}
```

But this crashes the node server. I've tried a few variations of it but can't get this working properly. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious or have a gap in my understanding here.

Please advise.

UPDATE:
This works now by adding the `$upsert` and `multi` options to the update function like so:

```
exports.updateAd = function(req, res) {
    var conditions = { _id: req.body._id };
    var update = {};
    if (req.body.viewCount) {
        update.$push = {
            viewCount: {
                'date': Date.now(),
                'user': req.body.user
            }
        }
    }
    Ads.update(conditions, update, {$upsert:false, multi:false}, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.jsonp({
            'result': result
        });
    });
}
```

But from what I read in the documentation both of those properties default to false. So I'm unclear why they need to be explicitly set like this. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Comment: have you tried it in mongo CLI? only in mongoose it fails?

Comment: Just did. It works properly from the CLI: `db.ads.update({_id:ObjectId('5a530eb483a0e1122b24a251')}, {$push: {viewCount: {user:"555b97c3fcf9464d49276f03", date:Date.now()}}})`

Comment: It must have something to do with the `update = {}` `update.$push = ...` and not having the correct hierarchy in my update object...?

Comment: can you post a sample doc, before and after update?

Comment: added those update options for readability, issue is with the update hierarchy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try

```
var conditions = { _id: req.body._id };
var options = { $upsert : false, multi : false };
var update = { $push : {
        viewCount: {
            'date': Date.now(),
            'user': req.body.user
        }
}};

Ads.update(conditions, update, options, function(err, result) { ... }
```

Comment: Yep!! That worked! So what's going on there with the options? All I did was put the $upsert and multi properties into my update options object of the function and it works now.

Comment: no, the way you formed the update doc might be an issue. Can you post a doc before and after update, will see?